# RestKit 0.10.3 Save Issues

Tags: restkit

I've recently inherited an Xcode project making use of RestKit and have upgraded it to 0.10.3 to get it working under iOS6.

The JSON response object mapping appears to all be ok although I have an issue where certain child collections are not actually saved.

For example I have

```
syncResponse.newEntities.customers
```

and then each customer has an array of addresses.

I save after the didLoadObjects with the following call:

```
NSError* err = nil;
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore] save:&err];
```

I've found that this will only save the Customer and none of the Address data or any child collections.  When I navigate to the Customer view the address area is empty.

However if I add the following block of code before the save lines then a list of suburbs prints out in xCode output and the addresses are persisted and all is fine.

```
    for (Customer* customer in syncResponse.newEntities.customers)
    {
        for (Address *address in [customer address]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", address.suburb);
        }
    }
```

Is there any reason why this should be happening or should a different save method be called?

Any help would be most appreciated!